# vscode not rendering jupyter notebook in wsl2

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conda, wsl-2

I just started working with wsl2. I am trying to run tensorflow.
It works fine if i create a python file with `.py` extention.

However whenever i create a file with `.ipynb` and open it then it gives me this error: `Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state..}`

The jupyter notebook is working fine in the browser with this command in the terminal `jupyter notebook`

The problem is only in the vscode.

I have tried removing the caches which i learnt from the other answers but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) for VSCode.

Then, press F1 and select interpreter among those installed on your system:
[image: select interpreter]

(The one you use when you call `jupyter notebook` should work. It needs the module `ipython` installed.